# Configuring an Automapper custom value resolver to ignore zero-length list values

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper 6.0.2 as part of merging partially-populated objects onto existing fully-populated objects, where the null values of the partially-populated objects are ignored.  My use of a custom value resolver to ignore null values works but it doesn't work as I expect when I try to configure it to also ignore zero-length lists.

Here is the simplified code:

```
  public class cTest
  {
    public List<double> dList { get; set; }
  }

  public class ValueResolver : IMemberValueResolver<object, object, object, object>
  {
    public object Resolve(object source, object destination, object sourceMember, object destinationMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
      var collection = sourceMember as System.Collections.ICollection;
      if (collection != null && collection.Count == 0)
      {
        return destinationMember;
      }
      return sourceMember ?? destinationMember;
    }
  }

  [TestFixture]
  public class MergeTests
  {
    [Test]
    public void MergeTest()
    {
      var newObj = new cTest { dList = new List<double>() };
      var existingObj = new cTest { dList = new List<double> { 1, 2, 3 } };

      var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
      {
        cfg.CreateMap<cTest, cTest>();
        cfg.ForAllPropertyMaps(pm => true, (pm, c) => c.ResolveUsing(new ValueResolver(), pm.SourceMember.Name));
      });

      config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

      var m = config.CreateMapper();

      var testResult = m.Map(newObj, existingObj);

      Assert.AreEqual(new List<double>() { 1, 2, 3 }, testResult.dList);
    }
  }
```

When I step through it, the line `return destinationMember;` is being hit - so I am not sure why `testResult.dList` results in an empty list (the newObj value) as opposed to the destination (existingObj) value.

Can anyone help explain what I'm missing?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a condition that if `collection.Count == 0` is true then return `return destinationMember;`. It means that after mapping `destinationMember` is empty. So code is working as expected

```
  if (collection != null && collection.Count == 0)
  {
    return destinationMember;
  }
```

Currently via this line `var testResult = m.Map(newObj, existingObj);` you are mapping `newObj` to `existingObj`, if the intention to fill `newObj` with items of `existingObj` then you should `Map` reverse i.e. `var testResult = m.Map(existingObj, newObj);`

Comment: Actually the intention is to map newObj onto existingObj - it might not be obvious since newObj has no values, but that is what I'm testing: if a list value in newObj is empty (but not null), I want the existingObj value to prevail. When I step through that code, I see the collection (cast of the source value) being List<double>[0], which is expected, and the destination value is List<double>[3], which is expected.
It does return destinationMember, which I thought would mean that is the chosen value that will be set to the destination member (existingObj).